# how can I get return the data in nested for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikits

For the code below, I'd like to know how to get `data` to operate with machine learning in `scikit`.
By that I mean to call data without for, just like `print(data)` to show the data.

```
x = np.random.uniform(0,9,size = 100)
y = np.random.uniform(0,9, size = 100)

c = len(x)
v = len(y)

for a in range(c):  
    for b in range(v):
        data = [x[a],y[b]]
```

Comment: It is unclear, what your code wants to achieve. Your loop is unnecessary because `data` will be a list of two elements (the last element of `x` and `y` respectively). Are you looking for something like `data = list(zip(x,y))` (or even `data = list(itertools.product(x,y))`, i.e. `((a,b) for a in x for b in y)`) instead?

Comment: I think the OP doesn't know how to xfer these data into his `scikit` setup. So please share more with us. What operation is next, what is the signature of the `scikit` function you want to supply with data?

Comment: I will return the x and y into 2D model. ex x = [1,2,3] and y = [2,3,4] and merge it become data = [ [1,2], [2,3], [3,4] ]. in my code i'd like to merge x and y from random generator to data, and accessed it. And next step i will try it for Kmeans. it's my next code                                                                                    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 1)
kmeans.fit()

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than iterating in a for loop, use numpy's built-in concatenation methods. A short-cut for your problem would be using [np.c_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

```
>>> x = np.random.uniform(0,9,size = 10)
>>> y = np.random.uniform(0,9, size = 10)
>>> data = np.c_[x, y]
>>> print(data)
[[ 4.17625287  0.65042586]
 [ 0.86363075  5.76803241]
 [ 5.60804861  4.53155782]
 [ 5.09218028  2.21632802]
 [ 6.78485295  2.22956468]
 [ 4.02404425  0.34639777]
 [ 6.40337929  6.98969517]
 [ 3.79826214  1.29557794]
 [ 5.75174741  6.31052599]
 [ 0.15683548  3.71585267]]
```

which concatenates `x` and `y` (`N` size 1-dimencional vectors) into an `Nx2` array.

Comment: ok, thanks, i'll try it